# Global Vars in a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I need to load in some prices from a file (the server doesn't have a database set up):

```
PriceChicken:2.16
PriceRibs:1.84
PriceBrisket:14.00
PricePulledPork:12.00
PriceSides:5.00
```

The javascript block like this:

```
var price = {
    "PriceChicken": "1",
    "PriceRibs": "1",
    "PriceBrisket": "1",
    "PricePulledPork": "1",
    "PriceSides": "1"
};

function loadVars(){
    console.log(price["PriceChicken"]);
    $.get("price.txt", function(data){
        dataarray = data.split("\n");
        for(i = 0;i < dataarray.length; i++){
            var line = dataarray[i].split(":");
            console.log(price[line[0]]);
            price[line[0]] = line[1];
            console.log(price[line[0]]);
        }
    });
    console.log(price["PriceChicken"]);
}
loadVars();
```

Unfortunately the function inside of the $.get part can't seem to see the global price variable.
So for the first item it shows: 1, undeclared, 2.16, and then 1 again when it leaves the $.get function.
Is there a better way to get the global variable to work, or a better way to pull this information in?

**Edit:** I was stupid and didn't check all my vars. As my penance I'm going to do it the right way and learn to use JSON.

Comment: ...and you're sure that `line[0]` is `PriceChicken`? If you do `console.log( price )` after the for loop, what's the output?

Comment: Which server-side language are you using?

Comment: @jhonraymos What difference does it make?

Comment: @Juhana *sighs* Yes, it really was that easy. I shouldn't program before my second cup of coffee. I had a space in the txt file originally, then I removed it, but the browser was pulling the cached old version so it was price["PriceChicken "] instead

Comment: Why are you not just using a JSON file and use getJSON()? No need to process it. Also there is nothing in JavaScript that would output "undeclared", you mean undefined?

Comment: @epascarells Haven't tried using JSON before (mostly work with php and a database). I will have to check JSON out. Time to learn something new. Which works for the second part of my question "a better way to pull information in"

Comment: Seriously, just retrieve the data from the server is native JSON format.

Comment: I'll take either Juhana's "check the variable" or epascarello's "why not use JSON" if someene wants to give me an answer I can mark. I'm also blaming the cold meds, I'm not usually this slow. Then I can leave this as a monument to my stupidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.get` call is asynchronous. You are treating it as a synchronous call.

The line `console.log(price["PriceChicken"]);` is called before the file is processed.

Better to use JSON format.

**prices.json**

```
{
    "PriceChicken" : 2.16,
    "PriceRibs" : 1.84,
    "PriceBrisket" : 14.00,
    "PricePulledPork" : 12.00,
    "PriceSides" : 5.00
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var price = {};

$.getJSON("prices.json", function(data){ 
    $.extend(price,data); 
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the variable is undefined inside it. It would only make sense if the variable would be undefined *before* the get call is finished.

Comment: invalid data would explain it.

Comment: Yes, it would (and it did), but invalid data has nothing to do with asynchronous/synchronous calls.

Comment: but trying to read the value afterwards is going to not give the latest value. Use JSON as I said above, no need to loop, just a simple call `$.getJSON("prices.json", function(data){ $.extend(price,data); } );`

Comment: On a side note to anyone else that ever checks this, I also had to add in the JSON mime type and handler mapping so that it would work with the .json extension. $.getJSON did work correctly with .txt, in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = {
    "PriceChicken": "1",
    "PriceRibs": "1",
    "PriceBrisket": "1",
    "PricePulledPork": "1",
    "PriceSides": "1"
};

function set_price(key, value){
    price[key] = value;
};

function loadVars(){
    console.log(price["PriceChicken"]);

    $.get("price.txt", function(data){
        dataarray = data.split("\n");
        for(i = 0;i < dataarray.length; i++){
            var line = dataarray[i].split(":");

            // set price
            set_price(line[0], line[1]);

            console.log(price[line[0]]);
        }
    });

    console.log(price["PriceChicken"]);
}


loadVars();
```